# How to set transparent background during translate animation android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I've the following problem. I've a TableLayout and two TableRows. Both TableRows contain two ImageButton. When a button is clicked I want to fade out other three buttons and translate the clicked button at the center of the screen. When it is translated the top or bottom half disappeared like it's hidden by the other table row. I've tried to set transparent background of table rows, to set alpha=0, to change layout and also I've tried to use ScaleAnimation, but the problem doesn't disappear. How can i show the disappeared half? I post also the layout code and a link to the screen with the problem.

http://it.tinypic.com/r/1zejhir/5

`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/l34"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:src="@drawable/unor"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:onClick="translate"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:src="@drawable/unor"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:onClick="translate"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/l12"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:src="@drawable/unor"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:onClick="translate"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:src="@drawable/unor"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:onClick="translate"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to use "space" from other viewgroups, your view is **bound to the hosting viewgroup** (eg tablerow). It doesn't have anything to do with the transparent background. The solution would be to have **one viewgroup holding all your icons**. For example use a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I tried the RelativeLayout version and I edited my question with the new layout . Unfortunately there weren't changes. I also tried using bringChildToFront() and bringToFront() methods but nothing...

Comment: You should use one relative layout for all the children, not 2 ;)

Comment: Wow! It seems to work now! I'm ashamed of myself, I replaced only layout names but I didn't delete others children layout. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

make **transparent**

in **java** code-> `imagebtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

**xml**-> `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: I've also tried it but it doesn't work. The other buttons disappeared with a fade out animation which set alpha=0, but when the selected button, for example the bottom|right position one, translate at the center I view only the bottom half as shown in the screen I posted.

Answer (score 0):

create modify the styles.xml file resource in values folder, with following code

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>

<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

in manifest.xml file add the below step to which activity make you as transparent.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
```